# render the correct view after rails g devise:views user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to use devise, but after I ran `rails g devise:views user` it seems rails is still loading views from views/devise/... and not the correct views/users/...how to set it the right way?

Comment: - If you want to edit the sign in, sign up forms you could very well edit those files under views/devise/ .
- If you want view(other) files for users_controller, you could load it from views/users

I don't und why you want to change the way devise works when you could achieve what you intend.

Comment: Can you define "right way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure to add this setting to your config/initializers/devise.rb file?

```
config.scoped_views = true
```